# Form is not submitted to firebase

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that this type of question asked here but with the help of these my problem won't be solved

Component

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    this.serverData.storeData('Analysis/Student Course Review', f.value)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response,f.value),
        (error) => console.log(error),
      )
  }
```

in app-module I import `FormsModule` Form `@angular/forms` and also add in

```
imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
```

HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <h2> {{basicInfoData[0]}}</h2>
  <div class="form-control">
    <div>
      <label>
        <strong>Batch:</strong>
        <span> {{basicInfoData[1]}} </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <strong>Semester:</strong>
        <span> {{basicInfoData[2]}} </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <strong>Subject:</strong>
        <span> {{basicInfoData[3]}} </span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let data of currentQuestionsValue">
    <div *ngFor="let d of data.items " class="form-control">
      <p>
        <strong> {{ d.sno }}). </strong> {{ d.question}}</p>
      <div>
        <form>
          <label *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(d.options)">
            <input type="radio" name="option" [value]="d.options[key]">
            <span>{{ d.options[key] }}</span>
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to post all the values which are in form but it to not posted values and I do not find what is error

this is service

```
storeData(url, servers: string) {
    return this.http.post('https://onlinefeedbacksystem-d5978.firebaseio.com/' + url + '.json', servers);
  }
```

this is output in `console.log`
[image]

Comment: Is the storeData method getting called? Can you post it too?

Comment: @SakshamGupta I edited console output and storeData check now

Comment: Can you try http.put instead of http.post?

Comment: @SakshamGupta I 100% sure error is not in storeData because from another component it work fine
error is in this component or DOM which I Post here

Comment: Maybe then it could be because of spaces in 'Analysis/Student Course Review'? It might be breaking the url

Comment: @SakshamGupta Am I Right to find form value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170358/discussion-between-adeel-and-saksham-gupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is ngModel on html element? Try ngModel along with name property and let me know if it worked.

```
<input type="radio" name="option" [value]="d.options[key]" ngModel>
```